# Manage list of an specific class in 'for' loop - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's suppose that I have this Class.

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self, population, DHI, capital, name):
        self.population= population
        self.DHI= DHI
        self.capital = capital
        self.name= name
```

And I create a list of objects of this class like this.

```
american_countries = [
  Country(120000000, 0.762, "Mexico City", "Mexico"),
  Country(320000000, 0.919, "Washington DC", "United States"),
  Country(36000000, 0.920, "Ottawa", "Canada"),
  Country(40000000, 0.827, "Buenos Aires", "Argentina"),
  Country(18000000, 0.847, "Santiago", "Chile"),
  Country(10000000, 0.776, "La Habana", "Cuba"),
  Country(207000000,0.744, "Brasilia", "Brasil"),
  Country(16000000, 0.640, "Guatemala", "Guatemala"),
  Country(6900000, 0.693, "Asuncion", "Paraguay"),
  Country(8700000, 0.625, "Distrito Central", "Honduras"),
]
```

then, I call a method that asks the population of these countries, and if it does not meet the requirement of the question it must be erased from the list.

```
 american_countries = ask_population(american_countries)
```

For example, let's say that we ask if the country that the user choose has over 100 million of habitants, if the answer is yes, we must erase all countries from list excepting United States, Mexico, and Brazil.

I think that we must check all objects inside the list and ask for the population, but I don't know how to do that in Python because the function does not know the object Country, so it's not possible to do something like this pseudocode...

```
def ask_population(list):

    answer= input("Does your country has over 100 million habitants?")
    if answer== 'Yes' or answer== 'yes' or answer== "YES":

        for x in list():
            if(list[x].population < 100000000): 
                print(Pais.nombre)
                lista.pop(x)
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name; it shadows the built-in `list` type, which can lead to weird bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to get a new, filtered list:

```
def ask_population(list):

    answer = input("Does your country has over 100 million habitants?")
    if answer.lower() == "yes":

        new_list = [x for x in list if x.population >= 100000000]
```

This new list will give you a filtered version of your old list with only the elements that meet your condition.

Comment: or `if answer.lower() == "yes":`

Answer (score 0):

In python, you don't need to 'know' the class of an object to 'ask' it for a property, or to call a method.  If you do:

```
print myobject.population
```

Then, if `myobject` has a property called `population` or implements a handler to provide that property.. it will work.  If it doesn't have that, you'll get an exception.

If you want to test an object to see what it implements, use the python `hasattr` function:

```
# this will call methodname() on myobj.. if myobj is of a class that implements that method.
# otherwise it will do nothing.
if hasattr(myobj, 'methodname`):
    myobj.methodname()
```

Same with methods:

```
myobject.somemethod()
```

As long as myobject has a method called `somemethod` which (in this case) has no required arguments, it will work.. regardless of class.

You don't have to worry about the class of myobject, only about what methods or properties it implements.

PS:  To make your code that parses the answer a little nicer, you could do:

```
if answer.lower() == 'yes':
```

.. and that'll accept 'yes', 'YES', 'yEs'.. etc.